# WireMock memory consumption when idle

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I'm seeing strange memory consumption patterns when using WireMock for API-stubbing. Our mocks run in standalone mode in Docker containers, which can typically run unchanged for days.

Strangely enough, WireMock seems to be allocating memory when it's idle, i.e., when no requests are fired against the mock.

Here's a typical memory footprint of a freshly started instance with *no* requests fired against the mock (Request journaling is off, just in case):

[image: WireMock memory consumption]

The heap does get garbage collected just fine, so it shouldn't be too much of a problem, but I would have expected constant memory usage when WireMock is idle.

Is there any configuration option we could tweak in order for WireMock to stop allocating memory when it's obviously bored? Or do we just have to live with that?

We are using WireMock 2.26.2, btw.